# Validating inputted strings as URLs - worth it for security?

Tags: security, validation, url

In a web application I'm writing, I give logged-in visitors the opportunity to enter a URL to go with their uploaded picture, as a link back to their site.

I was going to validate the string entered to make sure it was a URL, but after mulling the complexity of the solutions out there, I thought maybe it's not necessary.

However, are there any security implications that I might be missing by not doing so?  (I'm thinking of situations where a valid URL might include some malicious scripting, or similar.)

Answer (score 2):

The security issue with URLs is less to do with their validity (though it's good to have basic checks in order to catch mistakes, and naturally you need to use the same input validation and output escaping code as you use for data in general); it's more to do with dangerous URL schemes.

Most notably `javascript:` URLs aren't really locations at all, but script content to inject into the page that links them, resulting in cross-site scripting vulnerabilities. There are other schemes with similar issues. Best is to allow only known-good schemes, for example by checking that the string begins with `http://` or `https://`.

Comment: Would checking that the string begins with `http://` or `https://` be sufficient?  Are there no ways to embed scripts or suchlike in strings that do begin like that?  Perhaps I ought to know about the "other schemes" as well!  Thanks!

Comment: There are no ways to embed script into an HTTP/HTTPS URLs, though naturally when you inject that URL into a wider context you still need to do the right kind of escaping to make sure the content can't break out of context (eg HTML-escaping when dropping into a document). There is however one nasty little-known issue where semicolons in a URL can confuse the parser for `<meta refresh>` in IE only, potentially causing cross-site scripting. Best avoid meta-refresh.

Answer (score 0):

This feature seems to be a perfect example for a [Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)) where the uploader links to a web page that triggers the CSRF attack.

To mitigate the risk of CSRF attacks, make sure that actions with site effects cannot be predicted by the attacking site. This is generally done by a so called token, a random value that is only known to your site and the logged-in visitors.

Comment: I understand the important caveat about CSRF and I'm trying to implement it throughout, though I'm not sure that there is any action in my web application that could be exploited as such - it merely shows photos with links back to the originating blog or whatever page.  The user uploads a picture, a link for their originating page and a link title.  I suppose I was wondering how I could make that as safe as possible. I wouldn't want links to be CSRF traps.  If there are general risks with this, then perhaps I can't make it safe, short of manually inspecting each link, which wouldn't be viable.

Comment: @JohnDoe Any action that an (authenticated) user can do on your page can also be forged by an attacking site in behalf of the victim, unless the action parameters cannot be predicted.

Comment: Well, assuming I use a session token matching method to prevent CSRF in my forms (and PDO prepared statements for subsequent database insertion), are there any other potential problems with allowing visitors to post a link (ostensibly to show the origin of their photo)?

Answer (score 0):

*Correctly* validating a URL is not trivial. You can [get close](http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls), but it still won't necessarily cover everything allowed by the RFCs. As long as you aren't *evaluating* the URLs as input, running html_escape() or your framework's equivalent should be a sufficient precaution to protect your site from casual string mischief.

You may need to research your framework to understand what precautions, if any, you need to make against cross-site scripting, SQL injection, and other related issues. Most things that can go wrong will relate to unsanitized input, but your mileage may vary quite a bit.

Protecting the *user* is probably not a reasonable design goal if you expect 100% safety. The web is not a protected sandbox, after all.

Comment: Sorry - what do you mean by _"As long as you aren't evaluating the URLs as input..."_ ?

Comment: @JohnDoe It means: "Never, ever run unsanitized input through **eval** or related methods, and don't treat user input as valid code."

Comment: I never use `eval()` and I always try to validate user input.  My question was rather wondering whether I should bother trying to determine if a URL **is** a URL.  Your in-depth example seems to indicate that it's not perhaps 100% possible.